# SQL query for finding a value in multiple ranges

Tags: sql, mysql

i have MySQL db that contains event's date and 3 ranges, i.e from1-to1, from2-to2, from3-to3
each range has  different price, i.e from1-to1 rate1 , from2-to2 rate2, ...

so that's 3 columns for each range: from, to and rate.

i'm trying to find the query that returns the rate for a given month, meaning finds the range that the month is in and returns the rate of that range.

any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your data model is not normalized. You should consider morjas suggestion about creating an additional table.

Below is a really ugly query that checks whether a date is in any of the three ranges, and then returns the matching rate.

```
select case 
        when date '2010-12-05' between range1_from and range1_to then range1_rate
        when date '2010-12-05' between range2_from and range2_to then range2_rate
        when date '2010-12-05' between range3_from and range3_to then range3_rate
       end as rate
  from events
 where date '2010-12-05' between range1_from and range1_to
    or date '2010-12-05' between range2_from and range2_to
    or date '2010-12-05' between range3_from and range3_to;
```

Comment: thank you. what do you mean by "not normalized"? and what is the "date" keyword doing?

Comment: The date keyword is a way of specifying a date literal. You tell the database that this string is to be treated as a date.

Answer (score 2):

If you make an extra table just for the ranges you would keep your schema in normal form and you could easy select the right rate: TABLE range, COLUMNS from, to, rate. With a foreign key linking to your original table. Then you could SELECT rate FROM range WHERE 'date' >= from AND 'date' <= to.