# SQL check value is within variable (and multiple) number of ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL table including two columns depicting a range of IDs; those ranges needs to be compared with a cell under a particular ID column in a second table - if it is within the range, inclusively, the row of the second table will be included in the return.

Edit: The ranges available are limited by a range of user-supplied dates.

I'm only familiar with the basics of SQL; before I start researching loops and predefined tabular functions, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
SELECT * FROM [ADataBase].[dbo].[AFirstTable]
  WHERE [ALongIDNumber] <=
     (SELECT [StartOfIDRange] FROM [DHL].[dbo].[ASecondTable]
     WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2010-01-21' AND '2010-01-22')
  AND   [ALongIDNumber] >=
     (SELECT [EndOfIDRange] FROM [DHL].[dbo].[ASecondTable]
      WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2010-01-21' AND '2010-01-22')
```

Currently, this returns the error
`Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2`
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`
Which I'm guessing is causing it to fluff up because there's several rows returned by the selects.

I've researched, and come across [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344197/sql-query-for-finding-a-value-in-multiple-ranges) of which the only answers are for fixed number of ranges. Because I query a table for the ranges, the number of ranges will change.

Due to the nature of this scenario, modifying the databases is a last resort.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results. I'm not clear from your narrative what the contents of these tables is meant to be, nor how they shape the results. Try to include some values in both tables that will *not* match your overall criteria, as well as some that do, so we can get a feel for what's being asked for.

Comment: [Screenshot of example tables](http://i.imgur.com/M3U9n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really unclear from your narrative, but I think that what you *might* be looking for is the concept of a Join:

```
SELECT * FROM
   [ADataBase].[dbo].[AFirstTable] first
       inner join
   [DHL].[dbo].[ASecondTable] second
       on
          first.[ALongIDNumber] between second.[StartOfIDRange] and second.[EndOfIDRange]
WHERE
   second.[date] BETWEEN '20100121' AND '20100122'
```

This will find rows in `first` that fit into any range of ID values that occurs as a single row in `second`. This does mean that if there are overlapping ranges of ID values in second, you might receive multiple rows in the result set, for a single original row in `first`.

> before I start researching loops...

Don't. Although there are some crude ways to perform looping in SQL, you really shouldn't go there. The idea behind SQL is you describe *what* result you want, and the SQL engine works out the best way to achieve that (whether that be, behind the scenes, looping, creating hash tables, spilling items to disk, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple join:

```
select st.*
from SecondTable st join
     FirstTable ft
     on st.id between ft.StartOfIdRange and ft.EndOfIdRange
```

You seem to have additional conditions on the date.  You don't explain them in the question, so I'm not sure how to incorporate them in the query.

I see after careful reading that the date is in the first table.  Well, you can add the range either in the `on` clause or a `where` clause:

```
select st.*
from SecondTable st join
     FirstTable ft
     on st.id between ft.StartOfIdRange and ft.EndOfIdRange and
        ft.[date] BETWEEN '2010-01-21' AND '2010-01-22'
```

In the event that you have overlapping ranges, you might want to do a `distinct` to remove duplicates:

```
select distinct st.*
```

Comment: The date is within a range too, I guess, would be the way to put it. Essentially, the `[date] BETWEEN ...` limits all the ranges of IDs available in `ASecondTable`, again inclusively.  I've modified my original post to explain this.

Comment: Having no idea what no_Plate is, your comment is not very helpful.

Comment: Without the "and ft.[date] " line, the codes shows all the rows in the second table; with the line, it only shows ones for which ALongIDNumber is empty. Good progress though!

Comment: Sorry about the wrong column name in my last comment. Hopefully, the screenshot should clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `2010-01-21` and `2010-01-22` are the min and max dates, respectively, you could use the `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions to obtain a single ID in each of the subqueries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [ADataBase].[dbo].[AFirstTable]
WHERE [ALongIDNumber] BETWEEN
(
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM [DHL].[dbo].[ASecondTable]
)
AND
(
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM [DHL].[dbo].[ASecondTable]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

oracle has Between Keyword for checking the ranges, please follow like this. sample for between keyword

```
SELECT * FROM [ADataBase].[dbo].[AFirstTable]
      WHERE [ALongIDNumber] between
         (SELECT [StartOfIDRange] FROM [DHL].[dbo].[ASecondTable]
         WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2010-01-21' AND '2010-01-22')
      AND   
         (SELECT [EndOfIDRange] FROM [DHL].[dbo].[ASecondTable]
          WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2010-01-21' AND '2010-01-22')
```

Comment: I'm afraid this returns the same error, Mr. Dileep. `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: if u are getting more then one value from subquery, we can go with >=any, <=any , <=all and >=all

Comment: The example in the question already uses `BETWEEN` twice - it's unlikely that the OP hasn't encountered it yet.