# Store multiple ranges in mysql table to make queries faster/easier

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, date-range

I have a data with multiple time ranges, for e.g. consider following columns

```
| from1 |  to1  | from2 |  to2  | from3 |  to3  |

| 06:00 | 07:30 | 09:30 | 12:30 | 13:30 | 15:45 |
| 05:00 | 06:30 | 08:15 | 14:40 | 16:30 | 18:25 |
```

Now if I want to search for a time say `08:30`, I would have to add 3 clauses in the query to match if the input occurs in range any out of all three from-to pairs.

In above case, it would return second row as `08:30` lies in the second from-to pair.

I want to know what would be the best practice to do this? It is ok even if I have to change my data model and not store those ranges in columns like I shown above. so that I can quickly and easily search through thousands of records

I can't think of a better alternative to this, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I found this when i was searching for this problem.

It seems like your data model is not normalized. You should consider morjas suggestion about creating an additional table.

Below is a really ugly query that checks whether a date is in any of the three ranges, and then returns the matching rate.

```
select case 
when date '2010-12-05' between range1_from and range1_to then range1_rate
when date '2010-12-05' between range2_from and range2_to then range2_rate
when date '2010-12-05' between range3_from and range3_to then range3_rate
end as rate
from events
where date '2010-12-05' between range1_from and range1_to
or date '2010-12-05' between range2_from and range2_to
or date '2010-12-05' between range3_from and range3_to;
```

ref.[SQL query for finding a value in multiple ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344197/sql-query-for-finding-a-value-in-multiple-ranges?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it. the data required in the query is already stored in 4 different tables, I am not sure if I should add one more table for this making a 5 table join query.

Answer (score 0):

Store your times as [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) and use [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

So:

```
where myDate BETWEEN '2011-03-18 08:30' AND '2011-09-18 09:00'
```