# How to view discontinuous records of sql query?

Tags: sql

After a SQL query, say I got 50 records. I want to view the records 5-11, 17-36 and 41-46 say.
How to do this? As the range is discontinuous , LIMIT, BETWEEN etc are not working.

Comment: Multiple `BETWEEN`s with `OR` should work for you. For example `col BETWEEN 5 AND 11 OR col BETWEEN 17 AND 36`.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? It definitely matters when answering this question. There are differences between them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query for finding a value in multiple ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344197/sql-query-for-finding-a-value-in-multiple-ranges)